# Pass multiple signals to Signal.map throws type-mismatch errors

Tags: elm

I am trying to print the mouse cursor's distance from the window center using elm - 0.15. For example, placing cursor at window center must print (0,0).

My code is,

```
import Graphics.Element exposing (show)
import Mouse
import Signal
import Window

relativeMouse : (Int, Int) -> (Int, Int)
relativeMouse (ox, oy) (x,y) = (x - ox, y - oy)

center: (Int, Int) -> (Int, Int)
center (w,h) = (w/2, h/2)

main = Signal.map show <| relativeMouse (Signal.map center Window.dimensions Mouse.position)
```

`elm-make basics.elm` throws at least 4 seperate `type-mismatch errors`

How to pass multiple signals  (`window.dimensions`, `Mouse.position`) to a function (say, `relativeMouse`) in elm 0.15?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments are the changes from what you have:

```
import Graphics.Element exposing (show)
import Mouse
import Signal
import Window

-- change type signature to match implementation
relativeMouse : (Int, Int) -> (Int, Int) -> (Int, Int)
relativeMouse (ox, oy) (x,y) = (x - ox, y - oy)

-- use // for integer division
center: (Int, Int) -> (Int, Int)
center (w, h) = (w // 2, h // 2)

-- 1) map center over Window.dimensions to get a signal of origin positions
-- 2) map2 relativeMouse over the signal of origin positions and
--    Mouse.position to get signal of relative mouse positions
-- 3) map show over the signal of relative mouse positions to display them
main = Signal.map show (Signal.map2 relativeMouse (Signal.map center Window.dimensions) Mouse.position)
```

To answer your last question: `Signal.map2` is what you use to map 1 function over 2 signals. Corresponding maps exist up to `map5`.

The Signal import line can also be changed to

```
import Signal exposing ((<~), (~))
```

to use the shorter signal mapping syntax, in which case the main line changes to

```
main = show <~ (relativeMouse <~ (center <~ Window.dimensions) ~ Mouse.position)
```